# ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded, variable will range from 0 to 3e33

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this strange problem with np.arange. I want to plot a simple equation which basically looks like y = Ax^{-1/3}(1-Bx^{4/3})^{1/2}

However, I can get a almost working-quality plot from wolfram mathematica with my provided equation but I am struggling to generate the same plot in python!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
x = np.arange(0., 10**33, 10**8.)

plt.plot(x**(-1/3)*(1.102*10**20)*(1-(x**(4/3)*2.424*10**(-45)))**(1/2))

plt.xlim(math.pow(10,31), 3*math.pow(10,33))
plt.ylim(5*math.pow(10,8), 2.5*math.pow(10,9))

plt.xlabel("M(g)", fontsize =13)
plt.ylabel("R(cm)", fontsize=13)
plt.show()
```

my variable x should run from 0 to 3e33 and I want to see the plot both in linear and loglog plot, but I am having memory issues with the x range and if I set a smaller range, I basically get no plot at all. I am sure I am doing something wrong here, I just do not see it. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to plot till 3e33? Isn't that a bit excessive. The nature of the plot can be assessed by using a smaller interval as well.

Comment: You are asking the `arange` function to generate a ndarray containing evenly spaced values from 0 to 10^33 with a step size of 10^8.  That's 10^25 points, which could not be stored in all the RAM that has ever been made.

Comment: @Clock Slave In principle, plotting a function from 0 to 3e33 is no different from plotting a function from 0 to 3.  It depends on how many points you want to plot within the interval.

Comment: Hi, for my case, the number of points is not important as long I get to see the curve, unfortunately, I can't see any curve if I set the range to be `x = np.arange(0, 10^33, 10^30)'. I am just interested to know in what condition I will get a nice curve for this equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in the code:

1. `x` has too many points. Reduce the number of points, to e.g. 1000 points.
2. `x` should not start at `0`, since `0**(-1/3)` is undefined (you cannot divide by 0). Thus a sensible definition of `x` may be

   ```
   x = np.linspace(1e30, 1e33, 1001)
   ```
3. The `x` values do not actually appear in the plot, since you only plot `y`, `plt.plot(y)` instead of `y` vs. `x`: `plt.plot(x,y)`

In total,

```
from __future__ import division # if using python 2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1e30, 1e33, 1001)
y = x**(-1/3)*(1.102*10**20)*(1-(x**(4/3)*2.424*10**(-45)))**(1/2)
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.xlabel("M(g)", fontsize =13)
plt.ylabel("R(cm)", fontsize=13)
plt.show()
```

will provide

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the corrections. but I have to see my plot for those exact x and y limits, to explain the physical importance of the curve. And I tried for both linear and loglog plot and nothing seems to come out for those limits.

Comment: I see. You want to show the `x` values on the x axis. See my updated answer.